How to use route between 3 components?
I have my application designed as:
App.js containing two route:

Login & Signup
HomePage.

HomePage has the layout as:
Header
Sidebar
ContentArea
The header and sidebar component are imported into home.
Now what I want is when I click of any entries of sidebar, I want its content to be loaded in the content area section.
I have tried using link of react router in sidebar and then route on homepage with link to each menu pages or components but that didn't work.
This is my App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginSignup />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

This is my header:
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className='header-container'>
      <div className='header-wrapper'>
        <div className='header-content'>
          <div className='intro-bar'>
            <h3>SideMenu Name</h3>
            <h2>Welcome, User!</h2>
          </div>
          <hr></hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

This is my sidebar:
const Sidebar = () => {
  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <div className='sidebar-content-menu'>
      <ul className='menu-list'>
        <div>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
        </div>
        <div>
          <li onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

And this is my home:
const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate('/');
  }

  return (
    <div className='home-container'>
      <div className='home-wrapper'>
        <div className='home-content'>
          <div className='home-content-side-menu-holder'>
            <h1>ZERO</h1>
            <div className='sidebar-content-menu'>
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='home-content-menu-content-section'>
            <Header />
            <div className='side-menu-content-section'>
              <div className='side-menu-content-viewer'>
               //i want my sidemenu links page to be displayed here.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

For now, I have removed
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home/item1" element={<Item1 />} />
  <Route path="/home/item2" element={<Item2 />} />
  <Route path="/home/item3" element={<Item3 />} />
</Routes>

from sidebar as resulted in errors.

Can you please clarify which version of react-router you are using? And when you say the "HomePage has the layout as: Header Sidebar ContentArea", do you just mean that you have a HomePage component with those 3 children components? And can you please post the code for how you have currently configured the routes?

i just got back to react after about a year. so the react router dom must be of latest release. cant check now as i am outside. and my homepage has two component header and sidebar and just a whole wide div for content view. i set up vscode freshly so everything there must be of latest stable release.

We can't address issues in code we can't see, so please do [edit] the post to include a complete and relevant [mcve].

Issue
The issue is that the Home component is rendered on a route path that doesn't allow for descendent routes to be rendered.
Solution
Using Descendent Routes
Append the wildcard "*" matcher to the end of the home page path so that descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.
Example:
App
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginSignup />} />
        <Route path="/home/*" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

Descendent routes build relative to their parent route, so remove the "/home" "prefix" on the descendent routes.
Home
const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <div className="home-wrapper">
        <div className="home-content">
          <div className="home-content-side-menu-holder">
            <h1>ZERO</h1>
            <div className="sidebar-content-menu">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="home-content-menu-content-section">
            <Header />
            <div className="side-menu-content-section">
              <div className="side-menu-content-viewer">
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/item1" element={<Item1 />} />
                  <Route path="/item2" element={<Item2 />} />
                  <Route path="/item3" element={<Item3 />} />
                </Routes>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


Using Nested Routes
Another way would be to render an Outlet where you want the sidebar routes to render, and render them as nested routes under "/home".
App
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginSignup />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}>
          <Route path="item1" element={<Item1 />} />
          <Route path="item2" element={<Item2 />} />
          <Route path="item3" element={<Item3 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

Home
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <div className="home-wrapper">
        <div className="home-content">
          <div className="home-content-side-menu-holder">
            <h1>ZERO</h1>
            <div className="sidebar-content-menu">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="home-content-menu-content-section">
            <Header />
            <div className="side-menu-content-section">
              <div className="side-menu-content-viewer">
                <Outlet />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


